# Which events are available to parent of active IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, iframe

I wanna open dynamically any 3rd party website into IFRAME with maximum area - width 100% and height 100%. My problem is how to close this IFRAME from parent, without using ugly overlay buttons [X] ? I now that parent can't receive mouse and keyboard events when active element is IFRAME. Any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    iframe.parentElement.removeChild(iframe);
}());
```

The funny looking wrapper function is just to keep our variable isolated from the rest of the code.

Then we select our iframe and save it into a variable so that we only have to select it from the DOM once and to keep our code clean.

Line three is where the iframe gets removed.  We can't remove it directly, so we have to go to it's parent element and remove it from there.

Comment: My problem is when to execute your script, because I can't use mouse and keyboard events, captured by IFRAME.

Comment: If you use Fullscreen API, you can press key ESC to exit fullscreen mode - I need same idea, but parent can't capture ESC keypress or dragging from top.

Comment: Added explanation to my comment above.  But I see that it wasn't quite where you were having trouble.   Iframes (especially from third parties) are kept isolated on purpose.  The 'X' button really is the best option.